# Subfloor or underlayment?

Tags: flooring, tile, subfloor, underlayment

So, I have been doing a lot of research and could not find a solid answer. There seems to be different opinions.

For my half-bathroom renovation, I am starting fresh. For flooring, for the first layer I am using 23/32 Advantech T&G, which is glued to the joists and then screwed down with 1-3/4" screws. Now, I want to install a second layer, 3/4" plywood, to meet the minimum 1-1/8" thickness for the large format porceline tiles I picked out.

Now, what I came across is that some people claim this second layer to be "underlayment" and some argues that it is still subfloor (second layer of subfloor) -- and with that, they offer two different installation methods:

Method 1: If it's underlayment, then you don't glue the second layer to the first layer, and should use a shorter screw (1-1/4") to fasten the 3/4" ply to the first layer without fastening to the joists. And maybe put some kind of felt paper in between the boards (optional).

Method 2: if it's the second layer of the subfloor, then you glue in between the boards, and use longer screws so the second layer, 3/4" ply, can also be fastened to the joists.

I understand the installation method, but I can't figure out what I am doing would be considered underlayment or second layer of subfloor?

I will also laydown 1/4" uncoupling membrane (Schluter Ditra) on top of the ply before installing the tile.

Comment: Schluter has lots of technical docs for this sort of thing. I'm sure that you can find a detail from them. Yup. There it is. First link under "Downloads" from https://www.schluter.com/schluter-us/en_US/Membranes/Uncoupling-(DITRA)/Schluter%C2%AE-DITRA-&-DITRA-XL/p/DITRA?language=en_US. DITRA Installation Handbook.

Comment: Where did your 1-1/8" thickness spec come from? Are your joists on 24" centers or something (subfloor and underlayment thicknesses are predicated on joist spacing, but your 3/4" + 3/4" is probably too much for even 24" spacing)? The 2 layers of 3/4" plywood sounds excessive.

Comment: I did read the handbook — this is why I have the methods laid out. Method 1 is from Schluter, which considers the second layer as an underlayment. 1-1/8” thickness came from the 24”X24” porcelain tile. Joists are 16” oc. My real question is really is the second layer I’m laying down is underlayment or second layer of subfloor — I know how to install it once that’s confirmed. There seems to be conflicting information

Comment: My understanding is that underlayment is a thin smooth surface(maybe plywood) under the flooring.  Sub floor is thick plywood/OSB/planks that might not be perfectly smooth/rough.  Two or more layers of 3/4 plywood will be sub floor.  ~1/4 Lauan Plywood will be underlayment.

Comment: @crip659, underlayment is also spec'ed as a plywood grade under [PS-19](https://www.nist.gov/system/files/documents/2021/04/08/PS%201%2019%20final%20WERB-approved%20%28NIST%20vers%2011-18-2019%29%2B.pdf). 5.6.3.1 characterizes it pretty completely. Face veneer knots get plugged. There's a maximum defect size spec for the veneer below the face veneer. The faces are touch sanded (defined at 2.61). Smooth and flat with minimal squishiness.

Comment: "Method 1"? You mean D-W16-T? It doesn't call for underlayment. What's the exact wording of your tile's 1-1/8" spec? If you have one sheet of plywood, then stacking a second identical sheet on top (with strength axes aligned) takes the floor stiffness to 200%. Glue them together (with strength axes aligned) into a composite and it's 800%. If your tile calls for a 1-1/8" subfloor but you couldn't source 1-1/8" material, then you should be gluing them together to get the increased stiffness that the tile spec intends. Especially if your Schluter details don't even call for underlayment.

Comment: The 1-1/8" sounds calibrated for 24" joist spacing and natural stone, not porcelain tile over 16" joist spacing. Flatness is usually a big deal for large format ceramic/porcelain tile, but not stiffness. Stiffness is a natural stone thing.